# Accessing type argument on a generic class of generic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Can't find a way and I am starting to think it's not possible but just in case I'll ask here.

Better explained with code..

I have this generic class definition, and I would like to be able to access the `List`'s type argument so I can define a method in the `GenericClassOfGenericType` that accepts a string(taken from the type argument of the list)

```
//class definition
public class GenericClassOfGenericType<TGeneric>{ }

var instance = new GenericClassOfGenericType<List<string>>();
```

I tried something like;

```
public class GenericClassOfGenericType<TGeneric<TValue>> { 
 public void ProxyAdd(TValue value){ }
}
```

But this doesn't work and can't find anything similar on google.

I can add a second type definition to the `GenericClassOfGenericType` and a validator in the constructor to be sure the generic list has this second type as type argument but it doesn't feel good at all.

[Edit]
Also can't find a constraint that forces you to assign a generic type as an argument (makes sense as generics are also strong typed, but it makes me think that's not possible).

Comment: Any particular reason why you need to specify the "List" part of it? Why not just `GenericClassOfGenericType<TValue>`? Let it deal with the internal construction of whatever `List<TValue>` it needs. I mean, do you _expect_ to be passing in some subclass of `List` or different implementations of `ICollection` or `IList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that:

```
public class GenericClassOfGenericType<TGeneric, TValue>
    where TGeneric : IList<TValue>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's my last option as it forces you to specify the type argument's type argument, still better than checking in the constructor :P

Comment: From MDSN Generics documentation:

"The usefulness of type parameters as constraints with generic classes is very limited because the compiler can assume nothing about the type parameter except that it derives from System.Object. Use type parameters as constraints on generic classes in scenarios in which you want to enforce an inheritance relationship between two type parameters."

I guess it's the same problem here, so i guess i mark your answer as a solution and move on. 
Thanks.